# MVVM UserControl Active Inactive State

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls, mvvm-light

I'm still learning the MVVM pattern, I'm using MVVMLight, and I came to this problem:

Let's say, I have 2 different viewmodels A and B, they are pages in my application, and they're alive all the time. Also, there is a service which just send messages through the messenger.

Both, A and B are subscribed to those messenger notifications.
However only 1 viewmodel(page in this scenario) is shown at the time on the Window. I place two buttons on the main Window, one for each viewmodel A or B, so I can go to viewmodel A or viewmodel B whenever I want. They do not dispose, just 'hide'.

(I'm using a CurrentViewModel approach like [Rachel Lim's post](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/navigation-with-mvvm-2/). I use it because I found it simple and useful. If you know a better approach, I gladly like to hear it.)

Now, as only 1 viewmodel is 'active', I do not want the other to receive those messages.
If the current Page is Viewmodel A, I don't want viewmodel B to receive messages.

This is what I've tried:

- I thought, to unsubscribe the 'inactive' viewmodel from the messenger notifications, however, how can I know when the viewmodel turns to 'inactive' state?
- I also thought to, create a property in the viewmodels "IsActive" or something alike, then when the CurrentViewModel in the shell viewmodel changes, make an iteration, turning every viewmodel "IsActive" property to false, except for the 'active' viewmodel. But, what if my viewmodels are not in a list? I think that wold be so clunky and inappropriate, there must be a better way.
- Then I remembered the [Cinch Series](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38030/WPF-If-Carlsberg-did-MVVM-Frameworks-Part-of-n) from Sacha Barber, and came to my attention the [View Lifetime Behaviors](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38278/WPF-If-Carlsberg-did-MVVM-Frameworks-Part-of-n#Lifecycle), and I liked that approach, for knowing Loaded, Unloaded, Activated and Deactivated events, howevever, in a UserControl (which is my Page with a DataTemplate), Activated and Deactivated are not available.

So:

1) What is the best practice to notify a viewmodel that it is the CurrentViewModel?

2) And disable messenger notifications to the non-CurrentViewModel in a navigation pattern (like Rachel´s, or if you know a better one, tell me to investigate it).

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

What about sending a message back to the window saying which is current and keeping track in the window with who is the current view/view model.

Comment: Hi. Yes, keeping track of the CurrentViewModel in the shell window is how Rachel's example works. However, the messenger notifications, are not received on the shell window, instead, are received in both viewmodels. If a viewmodel is not the current in the shell, it has to not receive notifications. That's why I tried adding the property 'IsActive', if IsActive == False, then the notification is ignored. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts both using custom message classes:

1) Does the sender of the message know which viewmodel is active? Part of the message payload could contain which viewmodel is to process it. Each viewmodel upon receiving a message can check the payload to see if it is suppose to process the message. However, inefficient because the inactive view model still receives the messages.

2) You could create an "ActiveMessage" custom message class with the payload being which viewmodel is active and sent from the shell. Each viewmodel stays subscribed to this message class. Upon receiving each "ActiveMessage" if it is for the viewmodel call an "RegisterForMessages" method - which registers the viewmodel for all other message types it needs. Later, when it receives an "ActiveMessage" message with a different viewmodel it calls "UnregisterForMessages()" method which unregisters from message while it is "inactive".

Comment: Hi. Your first idea came to me before, and after thinking it, I became aware that the inactive viewmodel will always receive the message. That's why I wanted another angle, with no luck. As I'm still learning, I cannot understand at all your second idea, I'll think about it for a time, 'till I get it. Maybe be useful in the future. Thanks for your time.